# Can you start a recipe on low and finish on high in a slow cooker?

Tags: cooking-time, crockpot

Thanks to a sick toddler I wasn't able  start my country style boneless beef ribs early this morning. The recipe calls for  8-12 on low or 4-6 on high. I've always been taught ribs should be low and slow never on high even in the crockpot.  Can I cook them on low for 5 hours or so and turn it to high for the last bit?

My crockpot does cook hotter and faster when on high then most with it cooking a normal recipe that is for 4-5 on high in about 3.

Comment: i would do high first so that any toughness will be worked out by the slow cooking.